# Creating repository in one Spring Boot accessing entities and database source from another Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created Spring Boot no.1 connecting to H2 databse (containing entities).
Now I have to create Spring Boot no.2 and Spring Boot no.3 and next Spring Boots which will connect to database Spring Boot no.1. How can I do that?
Morever, is it possible to create repositories and services in Spring Boot no.2 and 3 ? How would they create Spring Data - queries no knowing entities ? Or should Spring Boot no.1 contain repositories and services ?
In that case what's the architecture point of doing 2nd and 3rd Spring Boots to use no. 1 ?

Sping Boot no. contains database connection H2 and entities.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question? If it's an architectural question then you can add a diagram. This will to better understand the question and provide correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see this example, they did exactly what you asked

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-access-h2-database-multiple-apps

The key point here is overriding the default data source created by Spring Boot’s auto-configuration feature by adding a few properties to the application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

note : I will be giving a detailed answer here soon in case the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

you can:
in Spring Boot n1 you create the repository, that communicates with h2 db , and the entities associated, then you create a Rest controller where you set some enpoint that allows you to do the crud operation (insert,delete ecc),
in other Spring Boot (n2,n3) you can access that endpoint using [Feign](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-openfeign) rest client.
so in n2 or n3 you can for example call the get enpoint for retrieves a specific entity of the db.
of course you can customized your endpoint and add specific logic.
this is one , at my opinion, solution.
enjoy.